# How to set up an array in order to get radio button values without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am having trouble setting up an array in order to get the value of the radio buttons. These are the radio buttons that I have in my form:

```
<form name="artistImages"> //This is the form tag
```

```html
<legend> Gallery </legend>
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="Z"><img src="zedd.png" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="T"><img src="taylorswift.jpg" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="P"><img src="pharrell.jpg" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="B"><img src="beyonce.jpg" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="D"><img src="drake.jpg" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="radio" name="artist" value="E"><img src="eminem.jpg" height="82" width="68">
         <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="GetValue" onClick="getRadioValue(radioArray)"/><br>

<input id="image" type="text" name="name" size="20">
```

and this is the javascript

```js
<script>
var radioArray = [document.forms.artistImages.artist];
function getRadioValue(radioArray){
var i
var text = document.getElementById('image').value;

for (i = 0; i < radioArray.length; i++){
    if(radioArray[i].checked) return radioArray[i].value;
    var text = radioArray[i].value;
    };
    };  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script:

```
<script>
        function getRadioValue(){
            if(document.getElementById("artist1").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist1").value;
            if(document.getElementById("artist2").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist2").value;
            if(document.getElementById("artist3").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist3").value;
            if(document.getElementById("artist4").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist4").value;
            if(document.getElementById("artist5").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist5").value;
            if(document.getElementById("artist6").checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   document.getElementById("artist6").value;
            };  
    </script>
```

and this html:

```
<form name="artistImages">
        <legend> Gallery </legend>
        <input type="radio" id="artist1" name="artist" value="Z"><img src="zedd.png" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="radio" id="artist2" name="artist" value="T"><img src="taylorswift.jpg" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="radio" id="artist3" name="artist" value="P"><img src="pharrell.jpg" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="radio" id="artist4" name="artist" value="B"><img src="beyonce.jpg" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="radio" id="artist5" name="artist" value="D"><img src="drake.jpg" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="radio" id="artist6" name="artist" value="E"><img src="eminem.jpg" height="82" width="68">
        <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="GetValue" onClick="getRadioValue();"/><br>

        <input id="image" type="text" name="name" size="20">
    </form>
```

Comment: alright I've edited it in, I also have a fieldset between my radio buttons if that matters.

Comment: ok so theres a series of radiobuttons, when a radiobutton is checked and i click the 'mybutton', it should take that radiobuttons value and put it into the 'image' textbox. However when i select a radio button and click the 'mybutton' button nothing shows up int he textbox.

Comment: I have updated the Answer, i hope it is what you want. @Noctis

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified/generic version to complete the task:

```
<script>
    function getRadioValue(){
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length-2; i++){
            if(document.forms[0][i].checked)
                document.getElementById("image").value  =   (document.forms[0][i].value);
        };
    };  
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="artistImages">
    <legend> Gallery </legend>

    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="Z"><img src="zedd.png" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="T"><img src="taylorswift.jpg" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="P"><img src="pharrell.jpg" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="B"><img src="beyonce.jpg" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="D"><img src="drake.jpg" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="radio" name="artist" value="E"><img src="eminem.jpg" height="82" width="68">
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="GetValue" onClick="getRadioValue();"/><br>

    <input id="image" type="text" name="name" size="20">
</form>
```